# Pick two colors and get n colors in between

Tags: javascript, html, css, math, colors

I want to pick a given number of colors within a boundary. For example I give `#fff` and `#000` as boundaries and want 5 colors in between. How do I achieve to get `#fff, color 2, ..., color5, #000`, spread out evenly?

I want to pick colors for a charting tool based on a dynamic number of items in the chart. Just wondering is this can be done easily with code, or maybe there's an online tool for this already? Otherwise I'll manually pick the colors ;)

Comment: you can use rgb instead of hex
for example 
color1: rgb(255,255,255)

color2: rgb(0,0,0)

colors between: rgb(50,50,50),  rgb(100,100,100), rgb(150,150,150)

Comment: It is a bit wonky, but I did this once by making a canvas that was one tall, and n wide, applied my gradient to it, and then got the pixel data accordingly. It works great, and is basically what you want

Comment: Not wonky, actually pretty smart ;)

Comment: It was also really nice because I didn't want the color to change until closer to the end, so I made my custom gradient and my code simply kept checking the color instead of needing an if to tell whether the color had changed yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a function which gets an interval and makes an array with the interval and their multiples.

```js
function getInbetweenColors(color1, color2, count) {
    var array = [color1],
        c1 = parseInt(color1.substring(1), 16),
        c2 = parseInt(color2.substring(1), 16),
        interval = (c2 - c1) / count,
        i;

    for (i = 1; i < count; i++) {         
        array[i] = Math.floor(c1 + i * interval).toString(16);
        while(array[i].length < color1.length-1) {
           array[i]= '0' + array[i];
        }
        array[i]= '#' + array[i];
    }
    array[count] = color2;
    return array;
}

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getInbetweenColors('#fff', '#000', 5), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(getInbetweenColors('#0391f5', '#27333d', 5), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: This looks cool as well, but when I try it with my two base colors not all colors are valid; e.g. try with #0391f5 and #27333d. I think it's because the first color starts with a 0.

Comment: it was the expected length of the result. it takes now the length of the first parameter.

Answer (score 1):

[chroma.js](http://gka.github.io/chroma.js/) is an amazing library to do just that! - check out the `.scale` method [here](http://gka.github.io/chroma.js/#color-scales)